# Better optimization

Tags: java, optimization, arraylist

I am writing a piece of code that compiles fine but is kind of sloppy and can be optimized. Is there a better or easier way to do this. Also am I using the compareTo() method in the correct way? I am trying to use different ways to make the code cleaner and faster than the example below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sort {

    public ArrayList<Name> sort(ArrayList<Name> names) {

        ArrayList<Name> results;
        results = new ArrayList<Name>(); 

        do {
            Name firstName = new Name("zzz", "zzz");
            for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
                if (names.get(i).getFirstName()
                        .compareTo(firstName.getFirstName()) < 0
                        || names.get(i).getFirstName() == firstName
                                .getFirstName() && names.get(i).getSurName()
                                .compareTo(firstName.getSurName()) < 0)
                firstName = new Name(names.get(i).getFirstName(), 
                                names.get(i).getSurName());

            results.add(firstName);
            names.remove(firstName);
        } while (names.size() > 0);

        return results;
    }

}


class Name {
    private String firstName; 
    private String surName;

    public Name() {
    }

    public Name(String firstName, String surName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.surName = surName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getSurName() {
        return surName;
    }

    public void setSurName(String surName) {
        this.surName = surName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + surName;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return firstName == ((Name) other).firstName
                && surName == ((Name) other).surName;
    }



}
```

Comment: If you have to use selection sort because this is home work, it isn't meant to be efficient. If you want efficiency, I suggest you use the built in sorting routines for List. e.g. Collections.sort(list, your-custom-comparator)

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

> > Is there a better or easier way to do this. Also am I using the compareTo() method in the correct way?

Yes couple of issues:

- Comparing string should use equals method and not `==` like `firstName == ((Name) other).firstName`
- From the looks of it you are trying to sort names list. You are doing it probably with O(N^2) time. With JDK's sort, you could do the same in O(NlogN) time and hence making it worse than what you have currently.

So instead define your own comparator and use it like:

```
Collections.sort(names, new MyNamesComparator());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want efficiency I suggest you use the built in sort which `O(N * log N)`

```
// in Java 7
Arrays.sort(names, new Comparator<Name, Name>()) {
     public int compare(Name n1, Name n2) {
         int cmp = n1.firstName.compareTo(n2.firstName);
         if (cmp == 0)
             cmp = n1.lastName.compareTo(n2.lastName);
     }
});

// in Java 8
names = names.stream()
             .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Name::getFirstName)
                              .andThen(Name::getLastName))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```